# ASP.NET 2.0 C# Insert to database not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

I have an asp.net wizard control in my web application I am calling a stored procedure from code behind to insert data into database. Executing the proc in SSMS works fine and I had gotten this block to work once before and made changes (i unfortunately cannot remember which changes i made). My problem is that when the next button is clicked no errors are thrown and also no data is written to the database. I have tested by adding exception into the cnx2 try block and the exceptions were thrown so I know the code is executing to the place I want it to but it is still not inserting. Any help is appreciated Thank you. And please if there is any information i can add that may help let me know

```
     protected void onNextButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex.Equals(1))
        {
            page1Submit();
        }
        else if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex.Equals(2))
        {
            page2Submit();
        }
        else if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex.Equals(3))
        {
            page3Submit();
        }
        else if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex.Equals(8))
        {
            page8submit();
        }
    }
    protected void page1Submit()
    {
        string hispanic;
        if (cbIsHispanic.Checked)
        {
            hispanic = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            hispanic = "0";
        }
        bool newReport = true;
        SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(server);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[ReportCheckExists]", cnx);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportNumber", dReportNumber.Text.ToString());
        try
        {
            cnx.Open();
            int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            cnx.Close();
            if (rowCount > 0)
            {
                newReport = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error executing MyProcedureName.", ex);
        }
        if (newReport)
        {
            SqlConnection cnx2 = new SqlConnection(server);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("[NewReport]", cnx2);
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportNumber", dReportNumber.Text.ToString());
            try
            {
                cnx.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnx.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error executing MyProcedureName.", ex);
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            string strJavaScript = "<script language = javascript type=text/Javascript> alert('That report number already exists. If you need to modify a report select it from the main menu or enter the report number again.')</script>";
            this.Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("Key4", strJavaScript);
            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = 0;

        }
    }
```

Comment: "and the exceptions were thrown". If its throwing exception on cmd.ExectueNonQuery(), then surely it is not going to insert anything. What is the exception you are getting

Comment: Absolutely not related, but replace everything from `string hispanic` to `bool newReport` with `string hispanic = cbIsHispanic.Checked ? "1" : "0";`. Easy to read and saves you a lot of lines.

Comment: You should add `using` statements or finally blocks to avoid unclosed connections if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because you are executing the `cmd` command, and not `cmd2` in your second try catch block

Comment: after a few minutes sitting with my boss and then me bludgeoning myself with a hammer for being stupid found it thanks for the answer.

Comment: lol, np. Do take into consideration to use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements on your connections and readers btw, they are very useful, and they look pretty